# cv2.drawKeypoints not drawing keypoints on the outImage

Tags: python, opencv, keypoint

I am working with OpenCV in Python and trying to diplay the keypoints recognized by SIFT from gray image to the original color image. Here is my code

```
import cv2 as cv

org_img = cv.imread('/content/Sunset_org.jpg')
gray_img = cv.cvtColor(org_img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv.SIFT_create()
kp = sift.detect(gray_img,None)
sift = cv.drawKeypoints(gray_img, kp, outImage=org_img, flags=cv.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
cv.imshow('Sift Img', sift)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

I want the keypoints to be drawn on the original image, but instead it is being diplayed on the gray image. Did I misunderstand the use of the third argument, i.e. outImage? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see where keypoints are located, you need to use original image as a background. This is the first argument of `cv.drawKeypoints` function. The third one is the output image (keypoints + original image). Output image is returned. This API is strange but to draw keypoints properly use following syntax:

```
sift = cv.drawKeypoints(org_img, kp, 0, flags=cv.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! So if I keep outImage=org_img, does the original image get replaced with the (keypoints + original image)?

Comment: I suppose so but I'm unable to test it now.